# save radio button selection int string

Tags: java, android, string, radio-button, int

sry for the bad title but I don't know how to say what I am looking for.

My idea:
I want to develop an App with 10 Questions à 3 Answers.
I should look like this:

> Question
>
> 1st answer (Radio Button)
>
> 2nd answer (Radio Button)
>
> 3rd answer (Radio Button)
>
> Next Question (Button)

One of these answers gives 0 points, one 5 points and one 10 points.
So you can reach a miminum of 0 points and a maximum of 100 points.

Question:
Can i save the points as string/int and get it later as total?
That I can create a last Activity with:

> You reached X/Y/Z Points
>
> Text X/Text Y/Text Z

and with a specific text for that.
Let me say from 0-50 Points: Text Z "Try your luck again"
from 50-80 Point: Text Y "Not bad"
80+ Points: Text Z "You are awesome!"

I tryed to search for a solution but I don't know what to search for.
I started developing  3 Month ago.
It would be awesome if you can help me with some example codes in Java because I'm in the proceed of learning.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I created a similar app. You can get it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t3nxzzb2rc509s8/UlqN5xB8VX

Answer (score 0):

create public fields in each activity and count it in onCreate method